# printing html5 phone tag, prints the content and the href

Tags: css

I'm trying to print contact information.
When printing the phone number (I used the phone tag and the `href="tel:..."` it prints out:
`<phone-number>(tel:<phone-number>)`, e.g. 
`314-221-2234(tel:314-221-2234)`
instead of just the number:`314-221-2234`.
I've checked in Chrome and IE, both had this problem. 
Is this a bug? 
I've setup

```
@media print {
  phone {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

As a temporary solution.
Now it prints only the (tel:...)

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: There is no `phone` tag in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using something like HTML5 Boilerplate. Add this to your CSS:

```
@media print {
    a[href^="tel:"]:after {
        content: "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the phone tag, so now I have this:
     <a class="phone" href="tel:054-3322334">054-3322334</a>
On screen I see the number as expected, but when printing I still see the tel:054...., I tried to add the a[href^ to the @media, but it didn't make any change.

Comment: @user1443827 Did you add this rule to the very end of CSS file?

Comment: Moving the css to the end of the file did the trick.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no phone tag in html5. You can ref a phone number like so

`<a href="tel:+18008675309">800-867-5309</a>`

Comment: I believe that's what OP is doing. What about printing?